# Feature in SharePoint farm solution not showing web part items

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013, farm-solution

I have created a farm solution and added existing SharePoint items like Columns, CT, Event Receivers, Web parts.

While adding items to features(created manually) I can get site columns, CT, Event receivers. But cannot find Web part items into it.

Even tried to create new web part using add >> new item >> web parts .web parts get added to the solution but no feature is creating and cannot find it in any of the existing feature items.

Can any one suggest what I am doing wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Version of SharePoint 2013 or the UI Version its running in and the Features Web Parts are being deployed to they may not be visible unless deployed to the 14 hive folder or the 15 hive folder. 14 hive is 2010 Compatibility mode 15 hive is 2013 compatibility mode